# Rails 4 & Mongoid : date helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, mongoid

We just migrated from rails ActiveRecord to mongoid. In our view we could use the helper

```
<%= f.date_select :date, :use_two_digit_numbers => true, :order => [:day, :month, :year], class: "form-control" %>
```

However it's not working with mongoid as it is sending the parameters

```
date(3i)"=>"21", "date(2i)"=>"9", "date(1i)"=>"2014"
```

And rails throw a

```
Mongoid::Errors::UnknownAttribute
Problem: Attempted to set a value for 'date(3i)' which is not allowed on the model
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958052/datetime-with-mongodb-mongoid-and-rails-3-not-populating) mentions that mongoid cannot do that without including a module. But apparently my rails app doesn't recognise the module ?

```
uninitialized constant Mongoid::MultiParameterAttributes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arf, just found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5610896/mongoid-multi-parameter-attributes-problem-with-date) that mentions it has been removed in mongoid 4. I'll use this gem then

https://github.com/netguru/mongoid-sadstory

But if you have other alternatives....

Answer (score 0):

In the mongoid version 5, it looks like the multiple Parameter has been abandoned.

Now I use the html5 tag, like `date_field_tag` in the views, and in the controller action (create, update), I added a manual operation like `@article.write_attribute(:published_on, params[:published_on])` before the object save to the database.

Although it is an ugly solution, it works.